# Xcode Parse Issue -Unrecognized platform name ios _CLImageEditorViewController.m

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have added CLImageEditor in pod like pod 'CLImageEditor'. But I am getting this error:

[image]

I am transferring code from another mac. In new mac Podfile.loc file CLImageEditor version is 0.2.2 and my previous mac having 0.2.0 .So please help

Answer (score 0):

The `@available` syntax you're using is new to Xcode 9.

Are you sure you're using Xcode 9 on the new Mac?

Comment: Well yeah, that's your problem. That code will only compile in Xcode 9

Comment: Thank you for the reply!